# Как обрезать начало строки на js?

Tags: javascript, discord

У меня есть код, который обрезать конец строки, не зависимо кол-во символов с строке, но я абсолютно не знаю как обрезать начало строки, а конец оставить не зависимо от кол-во символов в тексте?

Код который у меня есть для обрезание конца строки:

```
let text = 'любой текст'; //сам текст
console.log(text); //полный текст
console.log(text.slice(0, -2);
```

Comment: а если отбросить возможность что в js есть супер функция для этого и логически подумать точнее изменить цифры в slice и посмотреть результат?

Comment: да и он не обрезает а создает копию того же текста но уже без 2вух последних символов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

См. использование метода [`String.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

Обрезать первые два символа:

```js
let text = 'любой текст'; //сам текст
console.log(text); //полный текст
console.log(text.slice(2)); // 'бой текст'
```